# Using strings containing single quotes as Javascript arguments within inline HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following Javascript (which is probably not the best style):

```
var string = "There's an error here";
parent.innerHTML = '<div onclick="foo(\'+string+\')">'+string+'</div>';
```

Because of the single quote, the resulting HTML is not valid:

```
'<div onclick="foo('There's an error here')">There's an error here</div>'
```

One solution is to use the element's own `innerHTML` as the argument to `foo()` (since the function argument happens to be the same as the content of the element).  However, this isn't a general solution.

Is it possible to deal with this issue using only an inline HTML solution?  In my case, the inline HTML is much larger, and I can't easily convert it to a more 'proper' form, using DOM functions to create and append the HTML, and closures for the onclick functions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you provide a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Why are you considering fixing this issue if you know is bad practice doing it that way? why not invest the time on doing it right?

Comment: @elclanrs I'm on a deadline :P  Also, I'd like to know if this is actually possible.  If it's not, this makes the above method functionally rather than just stylistically inferior.

Comment: @StefanDenchev Double quotes would prematurely end the onclick, and would fail always.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, though innerHTML would work like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4wGuU/1/) (or with jQuery's [html](http://jsfiddle.net/4wGuU/2/))...

Comment: @StefanDenchev Actually, `foo(this.innerHTML)` always works.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Oh, i see, that's great, then. Just to wrap this up, here's the code for the function i was talking about (in case anybody finds it useful): `function(p,s){var e = $('<div/>');e.html(s);e.click(function () { foo($(this).html());});p.append(e);};`, and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wGuU/4/).

Comment: As for the question, you can either use regex to escape the characters before you include the string, or a really cheaty trick would be to use [`escape()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) and [`unescape()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/bhqzC/) ^_^. There probably are simpler ways as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that your main issue is trying to attach event handlers using inline attributes instead of using `addEventListener`. All your issues will vanish if you respect good practices.

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
    foo("There's an error here");
});
```

However, if you still want to do it your way, you could simply escape the single quotes:

```
parent.innerHTML = '<div onclick="foo(\'' + string.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + '\');">' + string + '</div>';
```

Comment: The issue is the `foo(\'+string+\')`, not the inner HTML.  The inner HTML can take single quotes without ambiguity.

Comment: @1'', Oops that's just a careless mistake. Fixed.